# Can't set custom attribute in custom spinner class

Tags: android, spinner, drawable, android-custom-view

I am trying to set **right drawable** to my **custom spinner class** which extends **MaterialAutoCompleteTextView**. In my **constructor**, I can set icon variable with drawable coming from **custom attribute**. However, when I debug, icon is null in **setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds** method. Is it because it's called before I set my custom attribute in constructor? How can I set this value? Could you please help me out?

My custom spinner class as following:

```
public class CustomSpinner extends MaterialAutoCompleteTextView {


    Drawable icon;

    public CustomSpinner (Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomSpinner (Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);

        TypedArray a = arg0.obtainStyledAttributes(arg1, R.styleable.CustomSpinner);
        Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomSpinner_iconArrow);
        if (drawable != null)
            icon=drawable;

        a.recycle();


        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public CustomSpinner (Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
        if(icon!=null) {
            right=icon;
        }

        super.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

}
```

Here is my attrs.xml:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomSpinner">
        <attr name="iconArrow" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Here is how I use it in layout:

```
<com.deneme.test.CustomSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:iconArrow="@drawable/arrowdown"/>
```

Comment: add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` under  `<com.deneme.test.CustomSpinner`

Comment: already did, didn't change.